# Chrome Extension to forward an email

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, inboxsdk

I have to create a google chrome extension that will plug into gmail and add a button to the toolbar when reading an email as well as in the ellipses next to the reply button. When the button is clicked it should forward the email to a certain email address based off what is returned from an API call that passes the logged in yours email address.

I have been looking at InboxSDK as part of this and I am not sure how to add the button to the ellipses and also if it is possible to then get the logged in users email and then forward the currently open email with InboxSDK.

If anyone has any experience with this and can point me in the right direction that would be brilliant thanks.